# Powershell file renaming by filtering on more than one condition

Tags: powershell, file, rename

I've got a bunch of files in the following format:

```
00092-100221-01M-V-3-20-001 Building A, plan 1M Piping
```

I'd like to rename only the files containing both the words "Building A" and "Piping"
I've tried the following code

```
dir -filter "*Building A*", "*Piping*" | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.basename + " As built" + $_.extension}
```

but I get an error stating that the parameter -filter does not support this method.
Is there a way I can filter for 2 conditions in Powershell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `-Filter` parameter accepts only one argument. You could use the `-Include` parameter but this can be tricky (look at the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-5.1)).

The easiest way to filter pipeline elements in general is the [Where-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-5.1) cmdlet (short `where`):

```
dir | where { $_.Name -match "Building A" -and $_.Name -match "Piping" } | Rename-Item ...
```

Note: The `-match` operator uses regex matching, which is fine in this case. You could also use the `-like` operator with wildcards: `$_.Name -like "*Piping*"`